# Создание копии пользовательского класса

Tags: java

имеется пользовательский класс

```
public class Man implements Serializable{
    private HashMap<Object,Object> manMap;

    public HashMap<Object, Object> getManMap() {
        return manMap;
    }

    public void setManMap(HashMap<Object, Object> manMap) {
        this.manMap = manMap;
    }
}
```

Имеется некоторый код

```
Man man11=new Man();
        HashMap<Object,Object> dannie=new HashMap<>();
        dannie.put("Фамилия","Иванов");
        dannie.put("Имя","Иван");
        dannie.put("Отчество","Иванович");
        man11.setManMap(dannie);
        Man msn22=man11;

        dannie.put("Фамилия","Сидоров");
        dannie.put("Имя","Сидор");
        dannie.put("Отчество","Сидорович");
        man11.setManMap(dannie);

        System.out.println(msn22.getManMap().get("Фамилия").toString()+
                msn22.getManMap().get("Имя").toString()+
                msn22.getManMap().get("Отчество").toString());
```

Подскажите, каким образом создать копию объекта, которая не изменялась бы вместе с объектом. Необходимо оставить копию в таком состоянии, какой объект был до изменения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void setManMap(HashMap<Object, Object> manMap) {
    this.manMap = new HashMap<Object, Object>(manMap);
}

Man msn22 = new Man();
```

Comment: @Александр Результат другой. Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код.

Comment: Извиняюсь, не учел an msn22 = new Man();